# How to use a row value from one table as the name of another table in one query?

Tags: mysql

I don't even know if my title makes sense, so hopefully my explanation will make up for my lake of clarity with the title.

I want to create a single query that returns general information about my tables, the row count, average length, data length, min(id) and max(id) values, etc.

I know how to query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS` to get the 'size' information. For example:

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME AS Name,
    ->     TABLE_ROWS as 'Row Count',
    ->     AVG_ROW_LENGTH AS 'Avg Row Len',
    ->     DATA_LENGTH,
    ->     ROUND(DATA_LENGTH / 1024 / 1024) AS 'DATA_LENGTH(M)'
    -> 
    -> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
    -> 
    -> WHERE (TABLE_NAME    = 'event_log'
    ->        OR TABLE_NAME = 'event_log_policy_entries'
    ->        OR TABLE_NAME = 'event_log_policy_status');
+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| Name                     | Row Count | Avg Row Len | DATA_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH(M) |
+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
| event_log                |  10000089 |         182 |  1822425088 |           1738 |
| event_log_policy_entries |  10000137 |         171 |  1710227456 |           1631 |
| event_log_policy_status  |  10000094 |         244 |  2449473536 |           2336 |
+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.57 sec)

mysql>
```

Moreover, I know how to use the `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions on a per table basis to get their min/max ID values. (All three of my tables have a column named id).

```
mysql> SELECT MIN(id) AS 'Min', MAX(id) AS 'Max' from event_log;
+------+---------+
| Min  | Max     |
+------+---------+
|    0 | 9999999 |
+------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

However I don't know how to make this ***one query***. My goal would be to have a single table such as the following:

```
+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-----+
| Name                     | Row Count | Avg Row Len | DATA_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH(M) | Min | Max |
+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-----+
| event_log                |  10000089 |         182 |  1822425088 |           1738 |   # |   # |
| event_log_policy_entries |  10000137 |         171 |  1710227456 |           1631 |   # |   # |
| event_log_policy_status  |  10000094 |         244 |  2449473536 |           2336 |   # |   # |
+--------------------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-----+
```

I have been reading about table JOINs and SUBQUERIES but I have not been able to figure this out, yet. (I am assuming this can be done with a single query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague who isn't a stack overflow user referred me to an example, which I then extrapolated into the following:

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME AS Name,
    ->     AVG_ROW_LENGTH AS 'Avg_Row_Size',
    ->     DATA_LENGTH AS 'Table_Size',
    ->     INDEX_LENGTH AS 'Index_Size',
    ->     elog.Min,
    ->     elog.Max
    -> 
    -> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS AS isp
    -> 
    -> LEFT JOIN
    ->   (SELECT 'event_log' AS 'Name',
    ->           MIN(id) AS 'Min',
    ->           MAX(id) AS 'Max'
    ->    FROM event_log
    ->    UNION
    ->    (SELECT 'event_log_policy_entries' AS 'Name',
    ->            MIN(id) AS 'Min',
    ->            MAX(id) AS 'Max'
    ->     FROM event_log_policy_entries)
    ->     UNION
    ->     (SELECT 'event_log_policy_status' AS 'Name',
    ->             MIN(id) AS 'Min',
    ->             MAX(id) AS 'Max'
    ->      FROM event_log_policy_status)) AS elog ON (elog.Name = isp.TABLE_NAME)
    -> 
    -> WHERE (isp.TABLE_NAME    = 'event_log'
    ->        OR isp.TABLE_NAME = 'event_log_policy_entries'
    ->        OR isp.TABLE_NAME = 'event_log_policy_status');
+--------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------+
| Name                     | Avg_Row_Size | Table_Size | Index_Size | Min  | Max     |
+--------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------+
| event_log                |          182 | 1822425088 |          0 |   11 | 9999999 |
| event_log_policy_entries |          170 | 1709178880 |  137019392 |   33 | 9999999 |
| event_log_policy_status  |          244 | 2448392192 |  137019392 |  132 | 9999999 |
+--------------------------+--------------+------------+------------+------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.56 sec)

mysql>
```

It appears to be just as fast as the original query that didn't have the min/max values in it. I used `SELECT` and `UNION` to create a sub table with the name and min/max values and then joined it to the results from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITION TABLE_NAME.

Is there a better way of doing this? This works, and I feel good about figuring this out. But is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME AS Name,
    ->     TABLE_ROWS as 'Row Count',
    ->     AVG_ROW_LENGTH AS 'Avg Row Len',
    ->     DATA_LENGTH,
    ->     ROUND(DATA_LENGTH / 1024 / 1024) AS 'DATA_LENGTH(M)',
    ->     MIN(id) AS 'Min', MAX(id) AS 'Max'
    -> 
    -> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS, event_log
    -> 
    -> WHERE (TABLE_NAME    = 'event_log'
    ->        OR TABLE_NAME = 'event_log_policy_entries'
    ->        OR TABLE_NAME = 'event_log_policy_status');
```

It will return the filtered results from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS, and all of the results from event_log.

One question that I have though, is there a field in the event_log table that can relate to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS table, so that you can tie each row of the event_log to a row in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS table?

Comment: Sadly this only works for event_log, returning a single row instead of all three. I tried to extend this by changing the 'FROM' line to be [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS,event_log, event_log_policy_entries,event_log_policy_status] but that failed with the message "ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: Oh! And there is no relation between INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS and the event_log table other than the column TABLE_NAME in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS is the name of the table I am trying to get the MAX(id) value for.